# Изменение всех элементов вектора

Tags: c++

Есть двумерный вектор: `vector<vector<int>> a(n, vector<int>(c+1, 0))`. И хочется изменить все его элементы на определенну константу (например 1). Какая для этого есть функция?

Comment: Думаю лучше просто переместить другой вектор: `a = vector<vector<int>>( n, vector<int>( c + 1,  1) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

```
#include <algorithm>

std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto &v) {
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 7);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://onlinegdb.com/kaYQFgCwG)

Или, что то же самое:

```
for (auto &v: a) {
  std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 7);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня ошибка: ```error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘const int’)```

Comment: Сразу скажу, я не очень хорошо пишу на C++, но разве в случае двумерного вектора, `a.begin()` не будет итератором по векторам? И вы просто присвоите всем ссылкам внутри значение 1

Comment: Пропустил двумерность, добавил for_each

Comment: @vp_arth, мне интересно, `std::for_each` — это чисто функциональный выпендрёж? или это из-за того, что ОП спросил «функцию»? или ты действительно его используешь? если последнее, то по практическим соображениям или по идейным?

Comment: Почему нет-то? В основном, разницы нет. Обычно использую, если используемая функция может меняться. Если не может - то скореее всего напишу цикл)

Comment: А вообще, больше всего я пишу на плюсах в ответах на ruSO =)

Comment: я не против... просто это такая примечательно бесполезная конструкция: до 11-го года в с++ сильно не хватало цикла для прохода по всем элементам коллекции, но `std::for_each` ни кто не использовал т.к. не было лямбд, а после — ни кто так и не начал (в отличие от другой функциональщины) т.к. появился нормальный range-based for, который и по размеру меньше и читается/пишется проще... но почему-то в вопросах и ответах на ruSO `std::for_each` всё равно периодически всплывает... меня вот и интересовало, почему так происходит...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в общем случаи согласен, но если функтор, передаваемый в std::for_each уже написан как класс, который  хранит важную информацию, и эта информация меняется в операторе() и, например,  этот функтор нужно возвращать из функции, то можно сразу вернуть   std::for_each, так как он возвращает этот функтор. Это создает некоторое удобство

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, как сферическая идея в вакууме вроде и неплохо звучит, но представляется мне, что если встретишь такое ИРЛ, то первое, что сделаешь — загуглишь, что же всё таки возвращает `std::for_each`... а второе — грязно ругнёшься на «чересчур умного» автора...

Comment: Так можно говорить про абсолютно любой концепт в c++ =) Всё зависит от глубины знакомства с языком)